# Hidden inputs with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, hidden-field

I have a large table of data and a select field in each `<td>`. When selecting a value in that select field, I want to `POST` that value and an additional array to the server.
Unfortunately, the additional array is being ignored by Angular:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="compatibility.attributes" ng-value="[x.id, y.id]">
    <select ng-change="addCompatibility(compatibility)"
            ng-model="compatibility.rating"
            ng-options="rating.name for rating in ratings">
        <option value="">Rate</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Both `x.id` and `y.id` are being resolved correctly. But they're not being included in the `compatibility` object when sending my request. Instead, only `compatibility.rating` is being filled.

Comment: Can you share the code for addCompatability?

Comment: So far it's only:

    `$scope.addCompatibility = function(c) {console.log(c);})`

where the only value `c` holds is `rating`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here http://jsbin.com/kewopu/1/edit

Use ng-init instead of ng-value

```
 <input type="hidden" ng-model="compatibility.attributes" ng-init="compatibility.attributes=[x.id, y.id]" >
    <select ng-change="addCompatibility(compatibility)"
            ng-model="compatibility.rating"
            ng-options="rating.name for rating in ratings">
        <option value="">Rate</option>
    </select>
```